# How to save a nested one-to-many relationship in API-only Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources, fastjsonapi, jsonapi-serialize

In my Rails (api only) learning project, I have 2 models, Group and Album, that have a one-to-many relationship. When I try to save the group with the nested (already existing) albums, I get the following error, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Album with ID=108 for Group with ID=)`. I'm using the [jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) gem. Below is my current set up. Any help is appreciated.

**Models**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :albums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums
end


class Album < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**GroupsController#create**

```
def create
  group = Group.new(group_params)

  if group.save
    render json: GroupSerializer.new(group).serializable_hash
  else
    render json: { error: group.errors.messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

**GroupsController#group_params**

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group)
    .permit(:name, :notes, albums_attributes: [:id, :group_id])
end
```

**Serializers**

```
class GroupSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :name, :notes
  has_many :albums
end


class AlbumSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :title, :group_id, :release_date, :release_date_accuracy, :notes
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**Example JSON payload**

```
{
  "group": {
     "name": "Pink Floyd",
     "notes": "",
     "albums_attributes": [
       { "id": "108" }, { "id": "109" }
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the albums already exist, then `accepts_nested_attributes` is not necessary.
You could save them like this:

```rb
  Group.new(name: group_params[:name], notes: group_params[:notes], album_ids: group_params[:album_ids])
```

You will want to extract the album_ids as an array when passing it here.